# What is the most natural and native-like way to express this idea on friendship?

Tags: sentence-structure, alternatives, sentence

> *Since the first time we met us we are best friends.*

I think that this sentence is incorrect, and I am trying to find a good alternative without having to change everything. What do you think of these options? Please tell me if all of them are grammatically correct and also which one is the most natural and native-live.

1. Since the first time we met, we are best friends.
2. We are best friends since the first time we met each other.
3. We are best friends since the first day we met.
4. We became friends on the first day we met.

Comment: None of your first 3 versions are idiomatic - we use *Present Perfect* with "since", as in *We **have been** best friends [ever] since we [first] met*. But there are many other perfectly natural ways of saying the same thing using different verb forms. No particular way is the "right" way - all we can say is 3 of your 4 versions are *wrong* because of that present tense ***are***. So the question is Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: OMG of course! Totally missed that. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Would any of the sentences 1-3 be idiomatic/acceptable if they had the present perfect?

1. Since the first time we met, we have been best friends.
2. We have been best friends since the first time we met each other
3. We have been best friends since the first day we met

Comment: @E.V. yes, any of those would work. A shorter way to say the same thing would be "We've been best friends ever since we met"

Answer (score 5):

The error is using both "we" and "us"

The verb meet can used without an object.

The second error is to use the present tense. You should use the present perfect to mean "until the present".

> Since we met, we've been best friends.

Your (4) would be a good rephrasing.

Comment: But you could say *From the first time we met one-another...*

Comment: Yes, or more explictly "Since I met Sally, we've been best friends."  (assuming the friend's name is Sally)